# How does percentage work in height

Tags: html, css

I am making a little tic-tac-toe mixing html, js and css, however, I want to make the size of it adapted to any mobile or computer device. So, I need to, instead of determinate the size of my div in `px`, determinate in `%`. But there is a little problem: the percentage in related to the whole page, not only to the div. I have tried to make the height and widht of the html and body tags equal to 100%, but didn,t work.

Here is the code that matter

```css
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%; 
}

body {
    background-color: #9c9f84;
    margin:0;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
}

#myDiv { /* there is where the percentage is massed up */
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #e5e4d7;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10%;
    top:25%;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `vl` or `vh`?

Comment: How is it "messed up"? You're telling the div to be 100% the available width and 100% the available height, and positioning it absolutely so it's measuring based upon the window size, not any container. If you don't want the div to take up the entire area, don't use 100%. Are you expecting 100% to be less than 100%??

Comment: @Scott how should the position be like (instead of absolute for the container to have 100% width and be positioned where I want?

Comment: André 100% is 100%.. it's going to take the entire window. Again, if you don't want it to take up the entire window, 100% is **not** the proper percentage to use.

Answer (score 0):

How about a combination of width and padding, assuming you're after maintaining the aspect ratio of the squares. See this fiddle for a quick example: **https://jsfiddle.net/L6uz24gv/2/**

```css
.tile {
  background: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1%;
  width: 30%;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div id="tic-tac-toe">
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
</div>
```